# Cycling through JSON from database with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've made an AJAX call to my database using

```
$.post('getdata.php', {passLong: passLong, passLat: passLat},
      function(output){
```

output holds the JSON which was encoded in getdata.php. I'm trying to cycle through the JSON

```
     $.each(output, function(){
        console.log(this.CarParkName);
      });
```

In the console I just get 'undefined'. The jQuery each method is supposed to cycle through the JSON and plot markers on a map, the code worked when I had my PHP in the same file, but since using AJAX to get the data from the database, it doesn't work.

I've tried a few different things with the loop, but can't find out what's wrong.

Comment: Use google's cached version then: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YCCzEiL-qBIJ:api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/+&cd=1&hl=lv&ct=clnk&gl=lv&client=firefox-a

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the way he is using $.each?

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong. But the structure you are iterating over may not be what you expect. If its an array-like structure e.g. `{ "1" : { "CarParkName" : ".." }, "2" : { ...} }` then I see nothing wrong with that. If it returns a single object containing an actual array like `{ "data": [{"CarParkName" : ".."}, {...}] }` then you need to iterate over "output.data" but I don't think "each" is your problem.

Comment: example of it working with correct structure using $.each like you are http://jsfiddle.net/GNscE/

Comment: My JSON is like the latter, i.e [{"Address":"St Nicholas Avenue York Yorkshire","CarParkName":"McArthur Glen Designer Outlet","CarParkRef":"26"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My JSON is like the latter, i.e [{"Address":"St Nicholas Avenue York Yorkshire","CarParkName":"McArthur Glen Designer Outlet","CarParkRef":"26"}]"

Based on the comment discussion and your response to the other answer, I think the problem is you are dealing with a string, not a javascript object. You just need to parse the string into an object. (I had assumed you were dealing with data parsed into a javascript object already).

If the string looks exactly like that:

```
[{"Address":"St Nicholas Avenue York Yorkshire",
"CarParkName":"McArthur Glen Designer Outlet","CarParkRef":"26"}]
```

then do this:

```
// wrap as an object first, a plain array is not valid json 
var js = $.parseJSON('{"data":' + output + '}');

$.each(js.data, function() {
    console.log(this.CarParkName);
});
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working on this for a while and tried parsing as well but obviously didn't do it right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
for(var i in output) {
    console.log(output[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This returns characters one at a time from the JSON, how would I access values by their name?